# Merge list of tuples and list of integers

Tags: list, haskell, merge, tuples, zip

I am new to Haskell and currently learning about lists.

I have a list of marks

```
[("Tom", 87, 78, 67), ("Dick", 56, 45, 72)]
```

and I need to get the sum of marks and the average of it. This is my approach.

Create a function to calculate list of sum of marks of each candidate

```
sumOfMarks = (\(a, b, c, d) -> b + c + d)
```

and map that function to the original list

```
newList = map sumOfMarks [("Tom", 87, 78, 67), ("Dick",  56, 45, 72)]
```

create a function to calculate list of average of marks of each candidate

```
avgList = map (`div`3) newList
```

merge all the lists original, `newList` and `avgList`

Desired output is

```
finalList = [("Tom", 87, 78, 67, 232, 77.34), ("Dick", 56, 45, 72, 173, 57.67)]
```

Another question is - whether this is the best approach to solving the problem and is there a better way?

Comment: You can work with a mapping where you map each 4-tuple to a 5-tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a function that maps a 4-tuple to a 5-tuple, so the function looks like:

```
map (\(n, a, b, c) -> (n, a, b, c, …)) oldList
```

where I leave `…` as an exercise.

Note that [**`div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div) is integer division. If you need to work with floats, you can use [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-). In order to convert `Integral` numbers to `Fractional` numbers, you can make use of the [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) function.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the quick reply.. A question.. Does the function look like ````map (\(n, a, b, c) -> (n, a, b, c, …)) oldList```` or  you are stating that a custom function has to be made which is then mapped to the original list?

Comment: @radhikaiyer: you need to fill in the `…`, so the expression for the fifth element of the 5-tuple.

Comment: Hi.. I am sorry William .. I am still not able to get it.. Just started LYAH as my guide.. It only talks about creating custom functions for more than 2 element tuples.. is there any material you can refer me to where i can look at appending elements to tuples?

Comment: @radhikaiyer: one of the fundamental concepts of Haskell is that all data is immutable, so you do not append item, you construct a *new* tuple that can be seen as a modified copy.

Comment: Hi.. understood.. So what i have been trying is                                                          
  ````alist = [("a",1,2), ("b",5,6)]                                                                                     
       blist = [4,8]   newList = zip alist blist.. which gives   [(("a",1,2),4),(("b",5,6),8)]```` which does not get the element inside the tuple..

Comment: @radhikaiyer: imagine that the last item of the 5-tuples should be the sum of the second and third item, you can work with `map (\(n, a, b, c) -> (n, a, b, c, a+b)) myList` So now you need to alter the expression of the last item of the result of the lambda expression, such that it calculates the average.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236230/discussion-between-radhika-iyer-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

*(Leaving out the conversions necessary to use `/` instead of `div`)*

we can combine the three lists using `zipWith3`, or using list comprehensions with `zip3`,

```
finalList =
 = zipWith3 (\ (n,a,b,c)  s  avg  ->  (n,a,b,c,s,avg)) 
               list  newList  avgList 
 = [ (n,a,b,c,s,avg) | ((n,a,b,c), (s, avg)) <- 
                          zip list 
                              (zip newList 
                                   avgList) ]
 = [ (n,a,b,c,s,avg) | ((n,a,b,c), s, avg) <- 
                          zip3 list 
                               (map sumOfMarks list)
                               (map (`div` 3) (map sumOfMarks list)) ]
 = [ (n,a,b,c,s,avg) | ((n,a,b,c), s, avg) <- 
                          zip3 list 
                               (map sumOfMarks list)
                               (map ((`div` 3) . sumOfMarks) list) ]
 = [ (n,a,b,c,a+b+c,(a+b+c)/3) 
                     | (n,a,b,c) <- list ]
 = [ (n,a,b,c,s,avg) 
                     | (n,a,b,c) <- list
                     , let s = a+b+c
                     , let avg = s/3 ]
```

List comprehensions are usually much more visually apparent (i.e. easier to use) than the various combinations of `map`s, `zip`s, `zipWith`s, etc.